# is text overflow will work in phpspreadsheet?

Tags: php, codeigniter, phpspreadsheet

The problem I am facing is, I am not able to set cell value as text-overflow (not clipped or wrapped). It is always hiding with a red triangle sign in Libre Calc.

I have a sample .xls sheet that I need to replicate dynamically. I got successful in generating the same .xls sheet using PHPSpreadsheet library in Codeigniter framework.

```
$spreadsheet = new Spreadsheet();

$sheet = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet();

$sheet->setTitle('1');

$sheet->getPageSetup()->setOrientation(\PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Worksheet\PageSetup::ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
$sheet->getPageSetup()->setPaperSize(\PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Worksheet\PageSetup::PAPERSIZE_A4);

$query_date = $data['month_selected'].' '.$data['year_selected'];

$date = new DateTime($query_date);

$date->modify('first day of this month');
$firstday= $date->format('n/j/Y');

$date->modify('last day of this month');
$lastday= $date->format('n/j/Y');

$xrow = 1;
$sheet->setCellValue('A' . $xrow, 'Attedence for the Period Beginning From '.$firstday.' TO '.$lastday)->getStyle('I' . $xrow)->applyFromArray($borderArrayRowOther);
```

The Text in the cell always gets hide when I see it in office 365 and Libre Calc. I need to double click to show it fully. But I need it shows fully.

[overlapped text][1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zi3Pj.png

Answer (score 3):

You have to use

```
$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A1')->getAlignment()->setWrapText(true);
```

For more Information see [documentation](https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/recipes/#write-a-newline-character-n-in-a-cell-altenter).

According to this comit [this comit](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PhpSpreadsheet/commit/22190615ce4a0555d70c32c56e7f7b8a3288bb2c) this will be automaticly included in future releases.

Maybe you must/will use some autofit then take a look to [this code](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PhpSpreadsheet/issues/333).

Comment: I did mention in my question that, I do not want it to be wrapped. It will just overlap the blank cells adjacent to it and will show the full text. The text come in front of cells grid. I just added an image for example.

Comment: Per default the cells will not wraped be care full not to fill blanks in the other cells. If you will more controle the easiest way to do is to merge the cells.

Comment: is there any feature in "PHP spreadsheet" library like "Bring to front" like in Microsft Excel?

Comment: As far as I know not.